# Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 15 Incorrect syntax near ')'

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have been fighting with this query for 2 days and still can't find where the problem is.

The SQL query is like this:

```
select t2.transno,
  case
  when (Select Count (*)
        From v1
        where v1.transno < v1.transno) > 1 
  then (
    case
    when (Select Top 1 v1.transno
          From v1
          Where v1.transno < v1.transno
          Order By v1.transno Desc)=(T2.transno-1)
    then ' '
    else 'Missing Invoice')
  else ''
  end AS Marker
FROM v1 AS T2
```

It's giving me error message:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 15 Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

Comment: I think you'd be better to give us tables, data and desired output. You have 2 correlated subqueries per row in the SELECT which means bad performance. if it's quick, it because the optimiser realises v1.transno < v1.transno is trivial

Comment: Its for checking the sequence for invoice number,and if one number is missing then it'l display missing Invoice in the marker column.I have done it in access it work fine but when i change the syntax to run it in sql server 2005 then am getting error

Answer (score 1):

I guess you forget to put end in this statement :`else 'Missing Invoice')`
Try like  `else 'Missing Invoice') end`

```
select t2.transno,
  case
  when (Select Count (*)
        From v1
        where v1.transno < v1.transno) > 1 
  then (
    case
    when (Select Top 1 v1.transno
          From v1
          Where v1.transno < v1.transno
          Order By v1.transno Desc)=(T2.transno-1)
    then ' '
    else 'Missing Invoice'
    end )
  else ''
  end AS Marker
FROM v1 AS T2
```

Comment: i have tried your suggestion but getting this error.Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 34 The multi-part identifier "t2.transno" could not be bound.

Comment: @Monshine: are table names case sensitive? Try changing `t2` to `T2`.

Answer (score 0):

Your second case statement is missing an end, which it requires. Try this:

```
select t2.transno,
  case
  when (Select Count (*)
        From v1
        where v1.transno < v1.transno) > 1 
  then (
    case
    when (Select Top 1 v1.transno
          From v1
          Where v1.transno < v1.transno
          Order By v1.transno Desc)=(T2.transno-1)
    then ' '
    else 'Missing Invoice') end
  else ''
  end AS Marker
FROM v1 AS T2
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the answer, but I think that `Top 1` should be `Top (1)`. [(See here)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

`v1.transno < v1.transno` is always false = zero rows.

So your query can be rewritten as

```
SELECT v1.transno, 'Missing Invoice' AS Marker FROM v1
```

More seriously, it can be expressed more simply as

```
select t2.transno,
  case
       when foo.maxtransno IS NULL THEN 'Missing Invoice'
       ELSE ' '
  END  AS Marker
FROM
    v1 AS T2
    OUTER APPLY
    (Select MAX(v1.transno) AS maxtransno
          From v1
          Where v1.transno < t2.transno
          HAVING MAX(v1.transno) = T2.transno-1
     ) foo
```

Comment: Sorry am somwhat new to sql server.I have tried your solution but it says Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 50 The multi-part identifier "t2.transno" could not be bound.Sorry to sound stupid but whats the "foo" mean.Do i have to replace it?